# How do I include all customers in a sales trend mysql query, even the ones that have zero sales

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following sql query, that generates a sales trend report. However it does not include customers that have zero sales. How can I include all customers even the ones with no sales activity ?

```
    Select customers.CustCompanyName, customers.CustID,
    Sum(If(Month(orders.OrderSaleDate) = 1, (invoice_line_items.OrderItemQty * invoice_line_items.PosProdPriceUnit *
    products.ProdSize), 0)) As Jan,
    Sum(If(Month(orders.OrderSaleDate) = 2, (invoice_line_items.OrderItemQty * invoice_line_items.PosProdPriceUnit *
    products.ProdSize), 0)) As Feb,
    Sum(If(Month(orders.OrderSaleDate) = 3, (invoice_line_items.OrderItemQty * invoice_line_items.PosProdPriceUnit *
    products.ProdSize), 0)) As Mar,
    Sum(If(Month(orders.OrderSaleDate) = 4, (invoice_line_items.OrderItemQty * invoice_line_items.PosProdPriceUnit *
    products.ProdSize), 0)) As Apr,
    Sum(If(Month(orders.OrderSaleDate) = 5, (invoice_line_items.OrderItemQty * invoice_line_items.PosProdPriceUnit *
    products.ProdSize), 0)) As May,
    Sum(If(Month(orders.OrderSaleDate) = 6, (invoice_line_items.OrderItemQty * invoice_line_items.PosProdPriceUnit *
    products.ProdSize), 0)) As Jun,
    Sum(If(Month(orders.OrderSaleDate) = 7, (invoice_line_items.OrderItemQty * invoice_line_items.PosProdPriceUnit *
    products.ProdSize), 0)) As Jul,
    Sum(If(Month(orders.OrderSaleDate) = 8, (invoice_line_items.OrderItemQty * invoice_line_items.PosProdPriceUnit *
    products.ProdSize), 0)) As Aug,
    Sum(If(Month(orders.OrderSaleDate) = 9, (invoice_line_items.OrderItemQty * invoice_line_items.PosProdPriceUnit *
    products.ProdSize), 0)) As Sep,
    Sum(If(Month(orders.OrderSaleDate) = 10, (invoice_line_items.OrderItemQty * invoice_line_items.PosProdPriceUnit *
    products.ProdSize), 0)) As Oct,
    Sum(If(Month(orders.OrderSaleDate) = 11, (invoice_line_items.OrderItemQty * invoice_line_items.PosProdPriceUnit *
    products.ProdSize), 0)) As Nov,
    Sum(If(Month(orders.OrderSaleDate) = 12, (invoice_line_items.OrderItemQty * invoice_line_items.PosProdPriceUnit *
    products.ProdSize), 0)) As `Dec`,
From
    invoice_line_items Inner Join
    invoices On invoice_line_items.InvoiceNumber = invoices.InvoiceNumber Inner Join
    orders On invoices.OrderID = orders.OrderID Inner Join
    customers On orders.CustID = customers.CustID Inner Join
    products On invoice_line_items.ProdID = products.ProdID Inner Join
    ref_product_categories On products.ProdCategoryID = ref_product_categories.ProdCategoryID
Where
    ref_product_categories.ProdCategoryID != 4 And
    ref_product_categories.ProdCategoryID != 5 And
    ref_product_categories.ProdCategoryID != 6
Group By
    customers.CustID
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN somewhere... (To keep customers with no sales.)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to have all customers to be visible, you need to have them in your query.

Your Customer INNER JOIN Orders will prevent that since it will only get customers that have an order

I would try with a LEFT JOIN near your customer INNER JOIN to get all your cutomer and then the orders link to them (or not since it's a left join)

So it should look like something similar to this

```
SELECT * 
from Customer C
LEFT JOIN Orders O
ON C.custID = O.CustId
```

Comment: This only works if I start with the Customers table. With multiple tables,  starting with invoice line items, not sure if it is possible ?

Comment: Since you want to have all the Customers event the one without any orders, you need to get the whole table without filtering anything. Starting with the customers table is the easiest